# Git prompt won't colorize

Tags: bash, colors, git, prompt

I want my git prompt in bash to colorize (green for clean repos, red for dirty repos). Right now, it shows plain white text no matter the git state of my cwd/repo.

https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc-wi#L135-L138

Comment: The output of git is coloured by default. Which version do you have? Have you installed it from the repos?

Comment: git 1.9.1 from official Ubuntu repos

Answer (score 1):

Although there could be a problem in `/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt`, I think you need to wrap `PS1=...` into a function and set `PROMPT_COMMAND`. See https://github.com/sengaya/configs-and-scripts/blob/master/.bashrc#L104 and https://github.com/sengaya/configs-and-scripts/blob/master/.bashrc#L16 for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines to file `.gitconfig` in your `$HOME` (create it if it does not exist):

```
[color]
    ui = auto
```

Or, alternatively, change it with the `git config` command:

```
$ git config --global color.ui auto
```

Optionally, leave out `--global` to apply it only to the current Git repository.

Comment: The git info in the prompt has the color but the rest of the string that shows bash info loses the color though.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure git will use color with:

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

---

Using bash and with git installed from the up-to-date package (1.9.1-1).

Add the following to .bashrc and then restart bash:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ "'
GIT_PS1_DESCRIBE_STYLE='describe'
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
```

You don't need to change your .bashrc file as in the link you posted. That file eventually will be sourced anyway.

See /etc/bash_completion /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt and, more importantly, /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt on your system for comments that describe the uses of the above variables (and additional ones).

Changes in already tracked file cause the dirty displays--newly added ones don't. The describe part of the prompt is only displayed when on a detached HEAD.